# How can I find out what hard disks are attached to a Linux box?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partition

How do I find out what hard drives are attached to a Linux box? I'm hoping for a single command that can give me a nice list of all ATA/SCSI/etc drives.

I've catted `/proc/partitions` in the past to do this, but I wonder if that still works if there's a drive with no partitions on it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### `sudo lshw -class disk`

gives you everything but the mount point

```
  *-cdrom                 
       description: CD-R/CD-RW writer
       product: 52MAXX 3252AJ
       vendor: Memorex
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/scd0
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: QWS3
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: ZIP 100
       vendor: IOMEGA
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 12.A
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: ansiversion=5
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sda
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD800AB-00CB
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 04.0
       serial: WD-WCAA52477019
       size: 74GiB (80GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=90909090
```

### `sudo lshw -class disk -html`

Comment: I would use "lshw -C disk -C volume" to also include the partitions

Comment: and `-short` to have information easily grep-able

Answer (score 8):

`fdisk -l`

Comment: One problem I have with with fdisk is that it also shows or errors on dm-crypt devices, or lvm devices, sometimes I like to see the actual disks.

Comment: +1 as the default installes for Ubuntu and Debian I have access to don't have lshw

Comment: `fdisk -l | grep ^Disk`

Answer (score 8):

When I run:

```
# lsblk
```

it returns tree disk-partition with mountpoints (for those partitions that have):

```
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
+-sda1                             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
+-sda2                             8:2    0 278.4G  0 part
  +-vg_devlinux02-lv_root (dm-0) 252:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  +-vg_devlinux02-lv_swap (dm-1) 252:1    0    32G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                                8:16   0  14.6T  0 disk
+-sdb1                             8:17   0  14.6T  0 part
  +-vg_devlinux02-lv_home (dm-2) 252:2    0  12.8T  0 lvm  /home
sr0                               11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sdc                                8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
+-sdc1                             8:33   0   128M  0 part
+-sdc2                             8:34   0   2.7T  0 part
sdd                                8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk
+-sdd1                             8:49   0   2.7T  0 part
sde                                8:64   0   2.7T  0 disk
+-sde1                             8:65   0   2.7T  0 part
sdf                                8:80   0   2.7T  0 disk
+-sdf1                             8:81   0   128M  0 part
+-sdf2                             8:82   0   2.7T  0 part
```

Comment: that's very useful, as it also shows which drives/partitions are assembled into which RAID drives

Comment: `lsblk` works nicely with [`watch`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) to see when drives are attached, removed, or mounted. This is my currently favorite format: `watch lsblk -o tran,name,model,fstype,label,mountpoints,fssize,fsavail,fsused,fsuse%`. [Here's](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-the-lsblk-command) a tutorial about `lsblk` that also explains how to define which information to show about drives and their partitions.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to lshw:

```
hwinfo --disk
```

Also has '--short' option, if you're only interested in the /dev and model name and not all the details.

```
hal9k:~ # hwinfo --disk --short
disk:
  /dev/sda             Hitachi HDT72502
  /dev/sdb             Generic USB SD Reader
  /dev/sdc             Generic USB CF Reader
  /dev/sdd             Generic USB SM Reader
  /dev/sde             Generic USB MS Reader
```

Long version gives you more details then lshw:

```
hal9k:~ # hwinfo --disk 
16: IDE 200.0: 10600 Disk                                       
  [Created at block.243]                                        
  UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_serial_SATA_Hitachi_HDT7250_VFL104R62EUUTX
  Unique ID: 3OOL.JSHCimqnHw6                                                         
  Parent ID: CvwD.epf1vnVqQVC                                                         
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sda                                                          
  SysFS BusID: 2:0:0:0                                                                
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0       
  Hardware Class: disk                                                                
  Model: "Hitachi HDT72502"                                                           
  Vendor: "Hitachi"                                                                   
  Device: "HDT72502"                                                                  
  Revision: "V5DO"                                                                    
  Serial ID: "VFL104R62EUUTX"                                                         
  Driver: "sata_sis", "sd"                                                            
  Driver Modules: "sata_sis"                                                          
  Device File: /dev/sda                                                               
  Device Files: /dev/sda, /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_Hitachi_HDT7250_VFL104R62EUUTX, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT725025VLA380_VFL104R62EUUTX, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:05.0-scsi-0:0:0:0, /dev/disk/by-id/edd-int13_dev80                                                                                                                                        
  Device Number: block 8:0-8:15                                                                                                                                                     
  BIOS id: 0x80                                                                                                                                                                     
  Geometry (Logical): CHS 30401/255/63                                                                                                                                              
  Size: 488397168 sectors a 512 bytes                                                                                                                                               
  Geometry (BIOS EDD): CHS 484521/16/63                                                                                                                                             
  Size (BIOS EDD): 488397168 sectors                                                                                                                                                
  Geometry (BIOS Legacy): CHS 1023/255/63                                                                                                                                           
  Config Status: cfg=no, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown                                                                                                                         
  Attached to: #9 (IDE interface)                                                                                                                         

[...]
```

EDIT:

As for the packages availability. I'm using OpenSUSE 11.1. [**hwinfo** is in the standard repository](http://software.opensuse.org/search?baseproject=openSUSE%3A11.1&p=1&q=hwinfo), while [**lshw** is only available from unofficial one](http://software.opensuse.org/search?baseproject=openSUSE%3A11.1&p=1&q=lshw).

Comment: But you need the hwinfo package installed for this to work :'(

Comment: @Andor: true, but to have lshw you also need to install the package.

Answer (score 4):

/proc/diskstats will have stats on all your extant drives, whether or not they have partitions on them.

Answer (score 2):

I like:

```
lshw -class disk
```

which lists all disks and storage controllers in the system.

Answer (score 2):

`cat /proc/partitions` Is working even if there is no partition defined for disk.

My favorite is `lsblk` which shows very good detail about disks and partitions, and where they mounted. Also `file -s /dev/sda` can give you simple information too.

Answer (score 0):

```
# fdisk -l | grep Disk
```

is used to display list of harddisk on server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it changed at some point, but using `sudo lshw -class disk` did not work for me. On my system, Ubuntu 17.10, I needed to use the `storage` class:

`sudo lshw -class storage`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`duf`](https://github.com/muesli/duf) that conveniently groups devices by their type and shows disk usage per default.

Example output:

```
  ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
  │ 2 local devices                                                    │
  ├────────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬──────┬────────────┤
  │ MOUNTED ON │   SIZE │   USED │  AVAIL │  USE%  │ TYPE │ FILESYSTEM │
  ├────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼──────┼────────────┤
  │ /          │ 808.0G │ 443.1G │ 323.8G │  54.8% │ ext4 │ /dev/sda3  │
  │ /sda1      │ 108.0G │  59.5G │  43.9G │  55.1% │ ext4 │ /dev/sda1  │
  ╰────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴──────┴────────────╯
  ╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
  │ 5 special devices                                                   │
  ├──────────────┬──────┬────────┬───────┬────────┬────────┬────────────┤
  │ MOUNTED ON   │ SIZE │   USED │ AVAIL │  USE%  │ TYPE   │ FILESYSTEM │
  ├──────────────┼──────┼────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┼────────────┤
  │ /dev         │ 7.7G │     0B │  7.7G │        │ devtmp │ dev        │
  │              │      │        │       │        │ fs     │            │
  │ /dev/shm     │ 7.8G │   5.1M │  7.8G │   0.1% │ tmpfs  │ tmpfs      │
  │ /run         │ 7.8G │   1.3M │  7.8G │   0.0% │ tmpfs  │ run        │
  │ /run/user/10 │ 1.6G │  28.0K │  1.6G │   0.0% │ tmpfs  │ tmpfs      │
  │ 00           │      │        │       │        │        │            │
  │ /tmp         │ 7.8G │ 192.0K │  7.8G │   0.0% │ tmpfs  │ tmpfs      │
  ╰──────────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴────────┴────────┴────────────╯
```