# Dbus or Udev command to locate connected hardware

Tags: linux, udev

It's a dumb question. Once I knew this command, I used it two or three months ago but now it seems I can't recall it. I tried to look for it using Google but nothing happened :(

It's a dbus command which send a query to udev or something similar, basically I could do

```
mysterious_command | grep Storage
```

and I could see all usb storage drives.

(No, using mount it's not the same because it just gives me mounted partition and not if they are usb storage or whatever...or maybe it can and I didn't know about it).

Comment: See: [What's the best way to get info about currently unmounted drives?](http://serverfault.com/questions/190685/whats-the-best-way-to-get-info-about-currently-unmounted-drives) and [How can I find out what hard disks are attached to a Linux box?](http://serverfault.com/questions/5031/how-can-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-attached-to-a-linux-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for either `lshal` or `lsusb`.

Comment: Fyi hal is being deprecated

Comment: What's the new kid in town then? I need something like hal.

Answer (score 0):

Will dmesg or dmidecode get what you are looking for?

I don't have any connected USB media to try this against but `dmesg | grep Storage` returns:
`Initializing USB Mass Storage Driver
scsi1 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices

scsi2 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices

USB Mass Storage support registered`

Comment: thanks but it was "lshal". Usually you can do "lshw -C disk -C volume" but it's not useful to my purpouse.