# Determining if a remote linux server has CD drive

Tags: linux, hardware

I want to find out if there is a CD drive on a remote server running Red Hat Linux release 7.3 (Valhalla).

Based on what I can see in fstab, /proc/devices, /proc/ide/ide0/ it seems like there is a CD drive, but is there any way I can verify it?

Answer (score 2):

```
# lshw -C disk
```

Should give you what you want.

Edit: 
Already here : [How can I find out what hard disks are attached to a linux box](https://serverfault.com/questions/5031/how-can-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-attached-to-a-linux-box)

Comment: Neither hwinfo nor lshw are available and I don't want to install anything on it. Give you an upvote anyway as it may be useful another time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to run `dmesg` and see what devices were enumerated by the kernel.

Comment: Have tried. The server has an uptime of over 200 days so anything from the boot is gone long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check what can tell you /var/log/dmesg for IDE devices.
Try to use "eject" command and see what will tell you.